# Finding device network disconnection location (which hop failed)

Tags: networking, ping

If you can't connect to the internet and you know the problem is as simple as one of your devices being disconnected along the line which of the following would you use to find out which? You also don't know the gateways or ips.

ping? Tracert? Pathping? View network map in the network and sharing center?

Comment: This question is Off-Topic because the user is just [spamming his homework across the network](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29522937/finding-device-network-disconnection-location-which-hop).

Answer (score -4, accepted):

DHCP or Static IP?

DHCP: 1)ipconfig /all 2) ping "default gateway"

Static: 1)tracert

If no luck, check your dns and/or try to connect with a website directly with the IP address.